# Azure Cosmos UDF to return default value if key doesnt exist

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, user-defined-functions

I have a document structure in Cosmos that typically looks like this:

```json
{
    "Item No": "123456",
    "Item Desc": "This is a description",
    "images": [
        "https://somedomain.com/image1.png",
        "https://somedomain.com/image2.png"
    ]
}
```

Sometimes, there will be empty image values. I have written a UDF (user defined function) which will replace any empty values, with a default value:

```js
function missingImage(doc, prop) {
  if (typeof doc[prop] === "undefined" || doc[prop] === "" || doc[prop] === null) {
    return "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
  }
}
```

In the event an image url is blank, I get back this return (correct):

```json
{
    "id": "e3842b29-313c-4a84-bc94-bc43a9a55742",
    "Item No": "123456",
    "Item Desc": "This is a description.",
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
},
```

My `SELECT` query looks like this:

`"c.id, c['Item No'], c['Item Desc'], udf.missingImage(c.images[0]) as image"`

However, in situations where no image key exists at all, for example:

```json
{
    "Item No": "123456",
    "Item Desc": "This is a description."
}
```

I don't get back my default.

**My question:** How can I modify my UDF or query, such that if the `images` key does not exist, I still return a default value?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?Crayons.

Comment: It does not, please see the response I've posted below.

Comment: ok. it's great you already have solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jay-gong for your time and response, however, this does not address the issue. I am looking for a way to return a default value when no `images` key exists in the document at all.

I feel the answer here, is not going to be through the UDF, rather it will need to be addressed at the query level. I am basing this off that fact that if I directly return a default, as you will see in the below UDF example, I don't get back `images` regardless.

The document in Cosmos:

```
{
    "id": "8fdc9f47-6209-455d-9b9c-482341bb3170",
    "Item No": "123456",
    "Item Desc": "This is a description."
}
```

The UDF:

```js
function missingImage(images) {
  return "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
}
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c['Item No'], c['Item Desc'], udf.missingImage(c.images) FROM c
```

The return:

```
[
    {
        "id": "8fdc9f47-6209-455d-9b9c-482341bb3170",
        "Item No": "123456",
        "Item Desc": "This is a description."
    }
]
```

**UPDATE:**
I have come up with a solution, which is to use `IS_DEFINED` to check if the `images` key is defined. If its not, return false, which then gives me something to act on within the UDF.

The query:

```sql
SELECT c.id,
       c['Item No'],
       c['Item Desc'],
       udf.missingImage((IS_DEFINED(c.images) = true ? c.images : false)) 
FROM c
```

The UDF:

```js
function missingImage(images) {
  if (images == false) {
    return "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
  }
  return images;
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this exact scenario. Did you ever find any better way to do this? It would be ideal if the UDF could pick up on undefined keys but it seems that we still can't

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the sample document you provided is incorrect format of json.

[image]

I suppose that it should be like:

[image]

You could modify the udf function like:

```
function missingImage(images) {
    for(var i =0;i<images.length;i++){
         if (typeof images[i] === "undefined" || images[i] === "" || images[i] === null) {
            images[i] = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

Then use sql to make sure no "" value in the results:

```
SELECT udf.missingImage(c.images) FROM c
```

[image]